# angular-ui-calendar undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui

I have problem with angular-ui-calendar using fullcalendar.
I don't know why it gets me undefined is not an object:

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'array.length')

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sources.length')

In controller, and yes i have uiCalendarConfig in controller definition

```
$scope.list = WorkingTime.query(function(){
            var result = [];
            for(var i = 0; i <$scope.list.length; i++){
                var helper = $scope.list[i];
                var helperFrom = new Date(new Date(helper.date).getFullYear(), new Date(helper.date).getMonth(), new Date(helper.date).getDate(), new Date(helper.from).getHours(), new Date(helper.from).getMinutes());
                var helperTo = new Date(new Date(helper.date).getFullYear(), new Date(helper.date).getMonth(), new Date(helper.date).getDate(), new Date(helper.to).getHours(), new Date(helper.to).getMinutes());
                var show = {title: helper.positions[0].name , start: helperFrom, end: helperTo};
                result.push(show);
            }
            $scope.source = [result];
        });
```

HTML

```
    <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="source"></div>
```

Please help me, have no more ideas. :(

EDIT

OUTPUT OF SHOW IN FIRST ITERATION:

```
{title: "Boss", start: Tue Nov 17 2015 11:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET), end: Tue Nov 17 2015 13:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)}
```

so it is correct. But still getting errors

Comment: Looks like your `$scope.source` is an array of arrays, is that really what you wanted?

Comment: it is what angular-ui-calendar want. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: Looked at the docs, they use an array of sources, you're using an array which contains 1 element which itself is the array of sources. By doing this declaration: `$scope.source = [result];` and by result being already an array (`var result = []`) , you're creating an array of arrays.

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ That example shows source being an array with three args [array, object, function]

Comment: Ok but even if ill write `$scope.source = result` it still gives me the same errors, so i don't think its matter of that.

Comment: can you make a plunker or fiddle so its easier for us to find a solution to the problem?